# how to set base64 url to image src

Tags: javascript, typescript, base64

Actually, I have an image using `angular-cli`:

```
<img src="" style="width: 120px; padding-top: 10px" alt="" id="dishPhoto">
```

and Base64 image url *imgUrl*. So I would like to set img src:

```
let img = document.getElementById('dishPhoto');
img.setAttribute('src',this.imgUrl);
```

but I get an error:

> document.getElementById(...) is null

Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: It can't be `null`, check for typo. What is in `this.imgURL`?

Comment: it wont be..recheck code and then console

Comment: Seriously, type of this.imgUrl is string

Comment: I'm using Angular. If I just create simple index.html then getElementById give me img

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure you code runs *after* the element is loaded (if your script is in your `<head>` tag, the element doesn't actually exist yet).

And if it isn't already there, you'll need to prepend the data metadata for images: `data:image/png;base64,` ([taken from including images in CSS](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-include-images-in-your-css/)).

Here is a working example.

```js
var imageData = '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'

var img = document.getElementById('dishPhoto');
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
```

```html
<img src="" id="dishPhoto">
```